# Codeigniter: Select Option return correctly but controller processes the results wrongly

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a view that returns the results of select option in HTML correctly.
The controller should use the selected option to load a specific view.
***Login View***

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" name="system">
           <option>--SYSTEM SELECT--</option>
           <option>Malaria</option>
           <option>Familiy Planning</option>
          <option>Laboratory</option>
      </select>
   </div>
```

At the controller, when I access the name value and use it to process data it does it wrongly.
***Login Controller***

```
    $system = $this->input->post('system');
        //if i echo system it will echo the correct value
        if($system = 'Malaria'){
         //view mal file
         $this->load->view('mal');
        }
        else if($system = 'Family Planing){
          $this->load->view('fp');
        }else{
          $this->load->view('error');
        }
    }
```

The controller still loads the view 'mal' template even if $system returns Family Planning.

Answer (score 2):

`$system = 'Malaria'` // assign the value Malaria to $system

for comparison use this Operator **==**. It  is an operator which tests
 equality and returns a `boolean`

`$system == 'Malaria'`

Answer (score 2):

change from

```
$system = $this->input->post('system');
        //if i echo system it will echo the correct value
        if($system = 'Malaria'){
         //view mal file
         $this->load->view('mal');
        }
        else if($system = 'Family Planing){
          $this->load->view('fp');
        }else{
          $this->load->view('error');
        }
    }
```

to

```
$system = $this->input->post('system');
        //if i echo system it will echo the correct value
        if($system == 'Malaria'){
         //view mal file
         $this->load->view('mal');
        }
        else if($system == 'Family Planning'){
          $this->load->view('fp');
        }else{
          $this->load->view('error');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `==` in place of `=` for comparison
And you are missing a single quote in `else if` statement,

Correct it :

```
if($system == 'Malaria'){
     //view mal file
     $this->load->view('mal');
    }
    else if($system == 'Family Planning'){
      $this->load->view('fp');
    }else{
      $this->load->view('error');
    }
```

**FYI**

The select option should have value. Like,

```
<select class="form-control" name="system">
       <option value="">--SYSTEM SELECT--</option>
       <option value="Malaria">Malaria</option>
       <option value="Family Planning">Family Planning</option>
      <option value="Laboratory">Laboratory</option>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your If condition is worng. please put on proper If condition,

```
 if($system == 'Malaria'){
         //view mal file
         $this->load->view('mal');
        }
        else if($system == 'Family Planing'){
          $this->load->view('fp');
        }else{
          $this->load->view('error');
        }
```

In your code $system again assigned. So that its viewing wrong file. correct is `if($system == "string")`

Answer (score 0):

Error Solved
The issues was I used one = instead of ==
at